# Setting "origin" in youtube-ios-player-helper breaks programatic functionality

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Using the YouTube iOS Player Helper library (https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper downloaded on 2015-06-16), if I add the line:

```
@"origin": @"example.com",
```

before:

```
@"modestbranding": @1
```

at line 30 in `SingleVideoViewController.m`, then the programatic controls no longer function to affect the video, and the progress bar no longer updates. Additionally, very few of the status messages are being shows/received.

I assume/hope "origin" would show up in analytics, to signify source, which is why I'm setting it.

Is there a specific format this text needs to be in, or something else I should be setting?

I'm cross posting this issue here as I have got no response to the GitHub issue
https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/121

Comment: I monitor the issues page and I can't reproduce the issue.  I add `origin` above `modestbranding` in my playerVars dictionary and can use the controls just fine.  Can you post your full playerVars dictionary and how you call `loadWithVideoId:`?

Comment: I download the repo above, followed the instructions for installing via CocoaPods, open the example project, and added the line above. I have tested on the iOS iPad simulator 7.2 and 8.3 via Xcode 6.3.2

Comment: `NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
      @"controls" : @0,
      @"playsinline" : @0,
      @"autohide" : @1,
   @"showinfo" : @0,
   @"origin": @"example.com",
      @"modestbranding" : @1
    };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing in a valid url for the `origin` parameter.

Try `@"origin": @"https://example.com"` or `@"origin": @"http://example.com"`.  Note the `http(s)://`.